# Write a query using sakila database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a query to give actor id, first name, and last name for all actors who have never appeared in a film rated ‘PG’.

Here is what I've done. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong, please?

```
select distinct actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
from actor, film, film_actor
where NOT exists
    (Select distinct actor.actor_id,actor.first_name,actor.last_name
    from actor,film_actor,film
    where actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
        and film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
        and film.rating = 'PG');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The not exists test for a condition and if the condition is true (exists)  return false  (not exists) 
then in you case you get correctly no result

could be you  need the actors not in you select

```
  select actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
  from actor 
  where actor.id NOT in 
      (Select distinct actor.actor_id 
      from actor,film_actor,film
      where actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
          and film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
          and film.rating = 'PG');
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the answer above, the line "actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id" inside the nested query is not necessary to get the same results.  Shorter version:

select distinct a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name from actor a where actor_id NOT IN (select distinct fa.actor_id from film_actor fa, film f where fa.film_id = f.film_id AND f.rating = 'PG');